# Merging objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have one javascript array:

```
[0: {name: "John", currency: "BTC", amount: 0.1298499}
1: {name: "John", currency: "USD", amount: 0}
2: {name: "Mike", currency: "BTC", amount: 0}
3: {name: "Mike", currency: "USD", amount: 0.01}
4: {name: "Mike", currency: "XRP", amount: 0}]
```

I want the output:

```
[0: {name: "John", btc: 0.1298499, usd: 0, xrp: 0}
1: {name "Mike", btc: 0, usd: 0.01, xrp: 0}]
```

Please use Javascript and consider that the first array could have infinite names and infinite currencies and at any time I could add a new item in this array with new name and/or new currency.

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Comment: How have the many JS array merge solutions on SO not worked for you?  Please show us your attempt and explain what isn't working with your code.

Comment: I tried many things, but with a lot of for loops I gets confused at the end.
=/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MayBe Like This:

```js
var data = [
 {name: "John", currency: "BTC", amount: 0.1298499},
 {name: "John", currency: "USD", amount: 0},
 {name: "Mike", currency: "BTC", amount: 0},
 {name: "Mike", currency: "USD", amount: 0.01},
 {name: "Mike", currency: "XRP", amount: 0}
];

function compile_data(_data){
 var out = [];
 var cur_arr = [];
 var name_arr = []
 for(var key in _data){
  if(!cur_arr.includes(_data[key].currency)){
   cur_arr.push(_data[key].currency);
  }
  if(!name_arr.includes(_data[key].name)){
   name_arr.push(_data[key].name);
  }
 }
 for(var kn in name_arr){
  var new_obj = {};
  new_obj.name = name_arr[kn];
        for(var kc in cur_arr){
         new_obj[cur_arr[kc]] = 0;
        }
        for(var key in _data){
         if(_data[key].name == new_obj.name){
          new_obj[_data[key].currency] += _data[key].amount;
         }
        }
  out.push(new_obj);
 }
 return out;
}

console.log(compile_data(data));
```

If need Lower Case :

```js
var data = [
 {name: "John", currency: "BTC", amount: 0.1298499},
 {name: "John", currency: "USD", amount: 0},
 {name: "Mike", currency: "BTC", amount: 0},
 {name: "Mike", currency: "USD", amount: 0.01},
 {name: "Mike", currency: "XRP", amount: 0}
];

function compile_data(_data){
 var out = [];
 var cur_arr = [];
 var name_arr = []
 for(var key in _data){
  var lc_cur = (_data[key].currency).toLowerCase();
  if(!cur_arr.includes(lc_cur)){
   cur_arr.push(lc_cur);
  }
  if(!name_arr.includes(_data[key].name)){
   name_arr.push(_data[key].name);
  }
 }
 for(var kn in name_arr){
  var new_obj = {};
  new_obj.name = name_arr[kn];
        for(var kc in cur_arr){
         new_obj[cur_arr[kc]] = 0;
        }
        for(var key in _data){
         if(_data[key].name == new_obj.name){
          var lc_cur = (_data[key].currency).toLowerCase();
          new_obj[lc_cur] += _data[key].amount;
         }
        }
  out.push(new_obj);
 }
 return out;
}

console.log(compile_data(data));
```

Comment: Some comments in the code would be helpful since the variable names are not helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what i was looking for! Thats when you know you need to practice a lot! XD

Comment: @Hugo Aroeira Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a standard grouping algorithm and collect all currencies in an object and take this object as pattern for not given currencies in an object.

```js
var data = [{ name: "John", currency: "BTC", amount: 0.1298499 }, { name: "John", currency: "USD", amount: 0 }, { name: "Mike", currency: "BTC", amount: 0 }, { name: "Mike", currency: "USD", amount: 0.01 }, { name: "Mike", currency: "XRP", amount: 0 }],
    pattern = { name: undefined },
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, { name, currency, amount }) => {
            r[name] = r[name] || { name };
            r[name][currency] = (r[name][currency] || 0) + amount;
            pattern[currency] = 0;
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(o => ({ ...pattern, ...o }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce will make this easy. Create a look up object and add the currencies to it.

```js
var users = [
  {name: "John", currency: "BTC", amount: 0.1298499},
  {name: "John", currency: "USD", amount: 0},
  {name: "Mike", currency: "BTC", amount: 0},
  {name: "Mike", currency: "USD", amount: 0.01},
  {name: "Mike", currency: "XRP", amount: 0},]

// Grab a list of all currencies with value set to 0
var currencies = users.reduce(function(obj, record) {
  obj[record.currency] = 0
  return obj
}, {})

// loop over the data with reduce to join the records
var mapped = users.reduce(function(obj, record) {
  // grab the name of the entry
  const name = record.name
  // check to see if we have seen it
  //if we have, use it, else create new record with name and currencies zeroed out
  obj[name] = obj[name] || Object.assign({ name: name }, currencies)
  // add the currency to the existing value
  obj[name][record.currency] = obj[name][record.currency] + record.amount
  // return the updated object to the reduce method
  return obj
}, {})

// turn our object into an array
var result = Object.values(mapped)

console.log(result)
```